# If there is only one post (show elements) else (show other elements)

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

So I'm looking for some help on an if statement:

```
<?php if(i dont know what to put here. [something like is-single-post]){ ?>

  <div class="one post"></div>

<?php }else{ ?>

  <div class="multi posts"></div>

<?php } ?>
```

Also this is a **custom post type** with a slug of **post** [ don't ask ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) ]. So im sure that will make a difference.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please give some more info on your idea? It would be very helpful.

Comment: What template is this on? Are you using a custom loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of posts in the current loop from the `$wp_query` object. How you do it will depend on whether you use the main loop or a custom one.

#### Main loop

Use the global query object.

```
<?php 

    global $wp_query;
    $is_single_post = ($wp_query->post_count === 1);

?>
<?php if ($is_single_post): ?>

  <div class="one-post"></div>

<?php else: ?>

  <div class="multi-post"></div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

#### Custom loop

Use your own query object.

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
            // fetch post type and whatnot
        );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);


?>
<?php if ($query->have_posts()): ?>

    <?php if ($query->post_count === 1): ?>

        <div class="one-post"></div>

    <?php else: ?>

        <div class="multi-post"></div>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```